# How to prevent an iframe to display external websites?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Let's say I display an iFrame on iframe.domain.com. I want this iframe to be able to display content from iframe.domain.com or sub.domain.com. But those websites contain link to external websites, for example google.com. If the users clicks on a link redirecting him to google.com, I want the iFrame to be redirected to sub.domain.com

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I want to expand what Arno_Geismar said.

You have other options:

1) HTML5!

```
<iframe sandbox="value">
```

The sandbox attribute will:

The sandbox attribute enables an extra set of restrictions for the content in the iframe.

When the sandbox attribute is present, and it will:

- treat the content as being from a unique origin
- block form submission
- block script execution
- disable APIs
- prevent links from targeting other browsing contexts
- prevent content from using plugins (through , , , or other)
- prevent the content to navigate its top-level browsing context
- block automatically triggered features (such as automatically playing a video or automatically focusing a form control)

The value of the sandbox attribute can either be just sandbox (then all restrictions are applied), or a space-separated list of pre-defined values that will REMOVE the particular restrictions.

[more info here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp)

2) Javascript: If you're using jquery you could simply put this

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $('a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Which is basically (almost) the same solution Arno_Geismar gave to you. The difference here is that I didn't need to loop through all "a" elements, thus improving a little the perfomance

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue and the solution I settled on was this:

1. Put a Content-Security-Police `meta` tag in your `<header>` section:

   ```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="frame-src https://desired_domain.com/">
   ```

   - [security.stackexchange.com - How can I restrict my iframe to only use local content?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/153404/161317)
   - [developer.mozilla.org - Content-Security-Policy: frame-src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-src)
2. Use the `sandbox` attribute in your `<iframe>` if you want to prevent links from opening a new tab:

   ```
   <iframe src="https://desired_url.com" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts"></iframe>
   ```

   - [W3Schools.org - HTML <iframe> sandbox Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `e.preventDefault()` to achieve this
to achieve this

now to get the onclick handler set on the links in your frame you can use this function

```
function onLoadIF(frame)
{
    var elements = frame.getElementsByTagName('a'),
        len = elements.length;

    while( len-- ) {
        $(elements[len]).on('click', function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I meant. I want the users not to be able to click on a link that would redirect the iframe to an external website.

Comment: @AdrienNeveu Hi adrien I updated my answer to fit your needs